# generateSharedAccessSignature not adding sv parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to generate a Shared Access Signature and am using the code here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2014/06/13/how-to-provision-a-shared-access-signatures-that-allows-clients-to-upload-files-to-to-azure-storage-using-node-js-inside-of-azure-mobile-services.aspx) for a custom API to generate the SAS.

It seems to be missing the sv=2014-02-14 parameter when calling "generateSharedAccessSignature()".

The SAS url doesn't seem to work when I try it (getting a 400 xml not valid error) but if I try a SAS generated from Azure Management Studio the URL contains the "sv" parameter and works when I attempt to upload with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [`Storage Service REST API Documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx), `sv` parameter in Shared Access Signature is introduced in storage service version `2014-02-14`. My guess is that Azure Mobile Service is using an older version of the storage service API and this is the reason you don't see `sv` parameter in your SAS token.

You could be getting 400 error (invalid XML) because of this. In the earlier version of storage service API, the XML syntax for committing block list was different than what is used currently. I have had one more user come to my blog post complaining about the same error. Please try the following XML syntax when performing a commit block list operation and see if the error is gone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
  <Block>[base64-encoded-block-id]</Block>
  <Block>[base64-encoded-block-id]</Block>
  ...
  <Block>[base64-encoded-block-id]</Block>
</BlockList>
```

Please notice that we're not using `Latest` node. Instead we're using `Block` node.

Comment: Hey Gaurav, I actually got it to work by leaving the sv parameter out and just adding the request header as part of the xhr:

xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version','2014-02-14');

So rather than having it be part of the generated SAS url, adding it as part of the PUT headers actually made the SAS work.

Not sure why the 400 XML error was coming back, the blocklist was exactly matching the syntax you have above in both cases.

Comment: If you're using `<Block>` element in your blocklist XML, change it to `<Latest>`.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the sv parameter out and setting it as part of the PUT request header worked using:

xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version','2014-02-14');

You can check out this example for an azure file upload script: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

...which will work with the generated SAS from the question's original blog link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2014/06/13/how-to-provision-a-shared-access-signatures-that-allows-clients-to-upload-files-to-to-azure-storage-using-node-js-inside-of-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Add the request header in the beforeSend like so:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version','2014-02-14');
},
```